# How to write a complete binary tree predicate using Prolog

Tags: prolog

What is the algorithm of checking if a Binary tree is a complete binary tree? (Using Prolog).

For example:

```
?- complete(nil).
true.

?- complete(tree(1,nil,nil)).
true.

?- complete(tree(1,tree(2,nil,nil),nil)).
false.

?- complete(tree(1,tree(2,nil,nil),tree(3,nil,nil))).
true.
```

Comment: What's the algorithm in English, for a start?

Comment: Well, I need all the leaves to be in the same distance from the root. So the most simple algorithm is going through all of them and check if all have the same distance from the root.

Comment: Perhaps a slightly quicker approach:  Find the depth of one leaf, then look for a leaf node that has less depth or a non-leaf node that has an equal depth.  If you find either of those, the binary tree is not "complete".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
complete(T) :- complete(T, _).

complete(nil, 0).
complete(tree(_, L, R), N) :-
  complete(L, N1),
  complete(R, N1),
  N is N1 + 1.
```

**update**:

It works for me:

```
?- complete(nil).
true.

?- complete(tree(1,nil,nil)).
true.

?- complete(tree(1,tree(2,nil,nil),nil)).
false.

?- complete(tree(1,tree(2,nil,nil),tree(3,nil,nil))).
true.
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns true for all the examples I showed above. If I understood what you have tried to do is to check that the right sub-tree and left sub-tree has the same height which doesn't define a complete binary tree.

Comment: @user550413: has you actually tried it? because it works with me, at least for the samples in your post!